# Angular 8: Use HostListener to Find DOM Element after a Mouse Click event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How do I find the current DOM element anywhere in the page, after a mouse click?
Currently trying to use HostListener in Angular 8.

```
@HostListener('click') onClick(){
    window.alert('Current DOM element is');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set second parameter with `$event.target`

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick(e){
  window.alert('Current DOM element is');
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks ! whats better for this situation anyway? hostlistener or other elementref answer

Comment: thanks! this works inside my component how do I make it capture items outside of the component? or is that not possible? i am testing this on child component

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 I can't tell. answers would vary with the situation. Adding more explanation to the post would be helpful.

Comment: gave points and accepter answer, feel free to thumbs up question

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ElementRef`

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('click') onClick(){
    console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-2-hostlistener-1b66d45b3e3d) is the link that explains that you can use a directive to detect a dom element and when it is present only then host listener should work.

Refer this:

[image]

Comment: It will be a great answer if you add/explain any code block from that link or way to do it!

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the guidance!